# Failing to install ubuntu 18.10

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 18.10 several times but failing to do so. I got stuck while installing the grub2 and it takes hours and hours. And the installation does not progress and I've to force shutdown the computer. I have manually tried to create partitions but if I include efi partition it shows the same problem but if I choose /boot partition it gives warning but I continue and installs perfectly but when restarting after complete installation it does not restart. If I force shutdown the system then it says "No OS Installed". I'm installing Ubuntu with no other OS on the system.

Answer (score 0):

In the laste detail that you provided to us, you say that you did install ubuntu

However 'OS not detected'

So I would suggest this to be a problem with booting with UEFI mode or Legacy mode 
which you can change while booting up by pressing F2

So the last time was the correct way you installed Ubuntu.